# CTRL+C and CTRL+Break are different?

Tags: windows, exception, console, signals

I've thought they are definitly same.
But I just found some values CTRL_C_EVENT and CTRL_BREAK_EVENT at [SetConsoleCtrlhandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Is there a difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the official documentation here: [<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd> Signals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I quote:

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd> is always treated as a
>   signal, but an application can change
>   the default <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> behavior in two
>   ways that prevent the handler
>   functions from being called